# How to create a secure login system using CI session and Base Controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a system where i have three users : **Admin**,**Reseller**,**User**. i am using codeingiter CI_Session class to store my sessions, And i store session when user logsin! My Problem is i don't want any usertype to access info of any other usertype. So i created diffrent base controller for each user. the urls as below

Admin URL: localhost/myproject/admin/secure/login
Reseller URL:localhost/myproject/reseller/secure/login 
User URL :localhost/myproject/user/secure/login

but now once a user or reseller logs in and writes admin in the url he can acess the information of admin. Now how to differentiate these?? i think my sessions are causing problem. i don't want to use any AUTH Library as i dont know how to use that as a i am new to CI. So please bear me and help me.

Comment: I suggest you to use Ion Auth, It is very easy to understand and customize. What you have done it is not effective and it will not include alot of methods that are already coming with Auth...

Comment: Yeah I went through the Ion Auth I think it will help me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use user type even in session. as a session variable.
In controllers you can add a validation check that is session is proper for that particular request or not.

For Example:
I used to do session array...when login is done...

```
$tempArray['user_id'] = 'user's id';
$tempArray['user_type'] = 'reseller/admin/user';
$this->session->set_userdata($tempArray);
```

Now in controller

```
if($this->session->has_userdata('user_type') && $this->session->userdata('user_type') == 'admin'){
//process admin login
}
```

This is very simple, but works all the time

Comment: Hello thanks for the  answer. But i already did this. I set a usertype at login. But when i login as administrator and just change the folder name in url to reseller i can view dashboard of reseller and vice versa

Comment: can you tell me once loggedin how do i prevent the user to view the admin page

Comment: at the time of login i code works fine it only lets user login if he has correct credentials but after login if i change the url is allows to access the details

Comment: In Controller before loading view you can check whether someone is loged in or not, if yes then load view otherwise call the login view like...$this->login();

Comment: done! cheers! but i have to check this usertype=="admin" in every function. is it not possible that i can just check it only once

Comment: Absolutely it's possible not to use all the time, you can make a model of Login, and use it's functions in controller, I have made it, and works fine.

Comment: Well for now i put that condition in all my controller methods and is working fine but from now will kep this in mind thanks buddy